# Gdalbuildvrt dosen't output the vrt file

Tags: gdal

I am trying to use `gdalbuildvrt` to create a time series of landsat images. I used the following code but it is not outputting the vrt file.

In the code `inlist` is the txt file with path to input image. However, if I list the individual tif files itself it would work. Any suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

[image]

[image: Inlist txt file]

Comment: Please use text with code formatting (the "{}" button above the question entry text area) not screenshots..

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a return value of 1 - which means an error of some sort.

Try using [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) or [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) so you get an exception raised if the command fails, you'll get a bit more about why it fails if you do this.

A couple of possible problems:

You are not passing the filepaths, you are passing the literal strings `"inlist"` and `"outVRT"`. Use `inlist` and `outVRT` (note lack of quotes) instead.

Your subprocess call will also fail if `gdalbuildvrt` isn't located in one of the directories in your `PATH` environment variable.  If that is the reason your command is failing, either pass the full path to gdalbuildvrt, or use os.environ to append the gdalbuildvrt directory to your `PATH`.

i.e:

```
subprocess.check_call([r"C:\Path\to\gdalbuildvrt", "-separate", "-input_file_list", inlist, outVRT])
```

OR

```
os.environ['PATH'] = ';'.join(r'c:\Path\to\gdal\bin\directory',os.environ['PATH'])
subprocess.check_call([r"gdalbuildvrt", "-separate", "-input_file_list", inlist, outVRT])
```